# How to identify if a byte string is a pickled object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

How to identify if a byte string object is a pickled object.

For example, in the below dictionary, how can I identify that `b` is a pickled object and that the other objects are not?

```
example = {'a':1, 'b':b'\x80\x03K\x02.', 'c':b'3'}
```

Comment: You could try to unpickle it, and if it fails see it as unpickled data. Pickle has a header, but it could be coincidence that the binary string has the same header.

Comment: [*"It's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission."*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although there are ways to tell whether it is *likely* that a stream is a pickle stream (for instance the first byte is always `\x80`, followed by the protocol number, here `\x03`, the last byte is also always a `b'.'`), in general it is hard to know that for sure (it could be coincidence that the first byte is `\x80` in a random string). So you better simply try to unpickle it and see if that works out:

```
import pickle

def is_pickle_stream(stream):
    try:
        pickle.loads(stream)
        return True
    except UnpicklingError:
        return False
```

The above method will return `True` if the stream is a pickle stream, `False` if it is not, and throw an exception if `loads` throws an exception (out of memory, etc.).

Comment: While I agree this is true test of identity, if the object is very big it would be unfortunate to try and unpickle the entire thing to confirm it is a pickle. You might as well just assume it is and return the unpickled obj and in the case of the unpickling error, return the str. But I think if just checking, the preemptive tagging you first highlighted is probably better.

Comment: String 'MHy.A.E.AJA.A.-N.P.C,' is not pickled but on pickle.loads it will not fail and give a number